# pd.to_csv set float_format with list

Tags: python, pandas

I need to write a df to a text file, to save some space on disk I would like to set the number of decimal places for each column i.e. have each column a different width.

I have tried:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10, 4)))
df.to_csv(path, float_format=['%.3f', '%.3f', '%.3f', '%.10f'])
```

But this does not work;

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for %: 'list' and 'float'

Any suggestions on how to do this with pandas (version 0.23.0)

Comment: can provide input data frame?

Comment: It appears from the docs that float_format doesn't accept a list.  It only accepts a string.  Hence, all floats are formatted the same using this method.

Answer (score 3):

You can do in this way:

```
 df.iloc[:,0:3] = df.iloc[:,0:3].round(3)
 df['d'] = df['d'].round(10)
 df.to_csv('path')
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the answers, inspired by @Joe I came up with:

```
df = df.round({'a':3, 'b':3, 'c':3, 'd':10})
```

or more generically

```
df = df.round({c:r for c, r in zip(df.columns, [3, 3, 3, 10])})
```

This is a workaround and does not answer the original question, `round` modifies the underlying dataframe which may be undesirable.

Comment: its nice! and smooth

Answer (score 0):

I usually do it this way:

```
a['column_name'] = round(a['column_name'], 3)
```

And then you can export it to csv as usual.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [applymap](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html#pandas.DataFrame.applymap) it applies to all rows and columns value.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(size=(10, 4)))
df.applymap(lambda x: round(x,2))

Out[58]: 
      0     1     2     3
0  0.12  0.63  0.47  0.19
1  0.06  0.81  0.09  0.56
2  0.78  0.85  0.42  0.98
3  0.58  0.39  0.73  0.68
4  0.79  0.56  0.77  0.34
5  0.16  0.20  0.94  0.89
6  0.34  0.79  0.54  0.27
7  0.70  0.58  0.05  0.28
8  0.75  0.53  0.37  0.64
9  0.57  0.68  0.59  0.84
```